# Lombok helps generate setters and getters.Is there anyway to autogenerate hasAttributeValue check in spring?

Tags: java, spring-boot, lombok

Lombok plugin helps auto generate getter and setter functions for a class attributes.

```
class User {
String firstName;
String lastName;

}
```

I have a need to add the empty check for the String attributes

```
public boolean hasFirstName() {
   return StringUtils.isEmpty(this.firstName)
}

public boolean hasSecondName() {
  return StringUtils.isEmpty(this.secondName);
}
```

I am looking for any possible way to autogenerate these has Value functions?

Comment: [Write your own](https://www.baeldung.com/lombok-custom-annotation)?  Note, adding it so that an IDE doesn't complain about it could be more complicated (since it wouldn't be included in the plugin's functionality).

Comment: Yes, writing own generator is an option. Want to ensure if there any available options prior to  that

Comment: Would creating in some class a static method called "has" that can be statically imported do as well? This way you would just call has(user.getFirstName()) whenever you need. It seems incredibly verbose having to write that same method all over the place.

Comment: Why don't use use Bean Validatoin?